# GraalVM mx build error: Could not find a GNU make executable on the current path

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gnu-make, graalvm

I was trying to setup [GraalVM](https://github.com/oracle/graal) on a Ubuntu 22.04 DigitalOcean droplet.

After setting up the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and adding `mx` to the `PATH` variable, running the `mx build` command in the `graal/compiler` folder produces the following error:

```
File "/home/javaApplications/graal/truffle/mx.truffle/suite.py", line 796 in definition of libffi:
Could not find a GNU make executable on the current path.
```

Please note that I've already found a solution to this question and want to share it with anyone running into the same issue. Look for my answer below and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `make` wasn't installed on my DigitalOcean droplet and had to be added to `PATH`.

So I installed it and added it to `PATH` via the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install make
which make
export PATH=<copy output from which make>:$PATH

// Then run the initial command:
mx build
```

Afterwards, if you get an error about a C compiler not being found, you'll have to install one and add it to `PATH`. Use the following commands to do so:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
which gcc
export PATH=<copy output from which gcc>:$PATH

// Then run the initial command:
mx build
```

Hope this helps!